# jquery-ui-datepicker update only first input

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to create 1 or 2 or more datepicker.

I've created a jquery code to do that but when the script is executed, both input elements open a datepicker, but only the first one is updated.

When I click on the second datepicker, the first input is edited. 
Any help?

that is the jquery code:

```
  $(".datepicker" ).each(function (){
    var max = "+0"; 
    if(typeof($(this).data('limit')) != 'undefined'){
        max = $(this).data('limit');
    }
    $(this).datepicker({
        yearRange: '-100:'+max,
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        maxDate: max,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
    });
  });
```

thank you!

Comment: Hi Jean-Philippe please add your html code (and put them in a jsfiddle for example, to help people trying to resolve your question)

Answer (score 0):

See if this will work.

```
   $(".datepicker" ).datepicker({
        yearRange: '-100:'+max,
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        maxDate: function(){
          // do some logic here and return max
          var max = "+0"; 
          if(typeof($(this).data('limit')) != 'undefined'){
            max = $(this).data('limit');
          }
          return max;
        },
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
    });
```